# vb.net equivalent of Using$()

Tags: vb.net, turbo-basic

Is there a modern vb.net equivalent to the [Using$()](http://www.powerbasic.com/support/help/pbcc/print_statement.htm) function in [Turbo?] Basic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/b1csw23d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: That's the same idea, but not what I need. I really need a direct vb.net copy of the old function, that deals with input and output exactly the same. FYI, that link was Italian.

Comment: This is what I ended up using. The trick was to replace the '#'s that were mandatory(the one right before and all the ones after the decimal point), with zeros.